# Can JSHint output warnings about globals

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jshint

Is there an option parameter to force JSHint to check for explicitly defined global variables and output a warning?

clarification: http://jsbin.com/odUcabUL/6/watch?js

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, you want to see a warning on `window.foo` (or `global.foo`) and on global-scope `var foo`? Or only the second one?

Comment: just when declaring foo in the global scope, i.e. var foo.

Comment: Why should that issue a warning? You *did* explicitly declare it there for a reason, didn't you?

Comment: in my new work environment, colleagues use variables outside of their respective function scope, polluting the namespace. they are not aware of this and i want to enforce it via linting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at ESLint, which is a completely pluggable alternative to JSHint. Has a lot of rules already and if you can't find what you're looking for in there you can always write your own rule. There's a grunt task available too.

1. https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-eslint
2. https://github.com/nzakas/eslint